# how to create create motion on multiple objects in a javaScript game?

Tags: javascript, html, debugging, game-physics, motion-detection

I am trying to make a dodger game in javascript and html, after many attempts I still do not know how to make multiple things move at the same time. I was trying to generate multiple opponent squares sliding from the top of the screen to the bottom of the screen, but all I managed to achieve was just generate a bunch of static squares on my screen.
any forms of help will be appreciated!!
my code:
https://repl.it/@HarryPengRHS/dodge

Comment: PS: my background and the player aren't showing up because of some reasons, please help! I am very new to javaScript.

Comment: Use canvas. New to JavaScript, or Programming altogether?

Comment: @StackSlave I am new to javascript however I have being using java for a few months now. Yes, I used the canvas element in my code.

Comment: In canvas, nothing is really an Object layer. You should save all of your states (use an Array of Objects - passing to functions to redraw) and redraw them after you `ctx.clearRect` on the canvas.